# Possible to move from a jquery mobile Grid B to a Grid A using CSS

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm using a Grid B as outlined in the [documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/content/content-grids-responsive.html). I'm wanting to know if it is possible to use css media queries to change from a Grid B to a Grid A without using javascript/jquery?

Comment: It's possible to have the same look but since there are **3 divs** in **GRID B**, you will have to lose one of them if you convert it to **GRID A**

Comment: Perhaps a better question then would be, what is the best way to do responsive web design for jquery mobile. Where say for example I have 4 objects in a row and depending on the screen size the objects in the row change from 4 to 3 and all the way down to 1?

Comment: Well, for specific deive.. set the first 3 divs `width` to `33.33%` and then make the last one to `100%`. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your needs, I have set the **Grid B** layout same as **Grid A** on `device-width` between **500px and 900px**. When the layout enters that zone, "Block A" and "Block B" will take half of the space of total Grid. And Block C will take the entire width of Grid and will go down automatically.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    .ui-grid-b.ui-responsive .ui-block-c {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ui-grid-b.ui-responsive .ui-block-a,
    .ui-grid-b.ui-responsive .ui-block-b {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/uv3uvemf/)** here

Hope, you get the idea!